# Offline documentation accesses Internet for trivial topics

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio (currently I am on VS2019) comes with the option to download the offline documentation and make use of that by default.

First one would have to make sure the Help Viewer is installed (from Visual Studio Installer) and then make that the default:

[image: Setting Help Viewer as default]

Then one can pick the help content downloaded for offline use:

[image: Enter the Add and Remove Help Content tab of the Help Viewer]

It looks like this:

[image: Choice of help content]

As you can see, except for a handful of topics I have installed most of the help content for offline use.

However, *regularly* when I use the offline help, I end up with links opening in my browser for no apparent reason. What's worse: more often than not you end up on some generic URL rather than something directly related to your search item.

**Concrete example:** in the Index or Contents look for `IFileOperation`. It should look something like this (as indicated by the colors, some of the related links were visited before):

[image: IFileOperation top of article]

When you click on the (highlighted) "Methods" link the Help Viewer directs to the default browser and opens the URL `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/`. This also happens to be the exact URL given if you look at the link properties for "Methods". Rather unhelpful.

**Question:** is there a way to use the offline help of Visual Studio completely offline even though the machine may be online? I.e. is it possible to prevent `https://`-URLs from opening altogether?